# "Cannot convert Python object argument to type '<typename>'" - error while wrapping c++-classes with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I'm trying to run a cython example which is a bit more complex than the one which can be found in many tutorials (e.g. [this guide](https://medium.com/@shamir.stav_83310/making-your-c-library-callable-from-python-by-wrapping-it-with-cython-b09db35012a3) ).

Here are a minimal example (please don't mind it doesn't have much functionality) and steps to reproduce my problem:

There are c++-classes`Rectangle` and `Group2` (I put here everything into the .h file to make it shorter):

```
// Rectangle.h
namespace shapes { 
    class Rectangle {
        public:
            Rectangle() {}
    };

    class Group2 {
    public:
        Group2(Rectangle rect0, Rectangle rect1) {}
    };
}
```

Then I create a *grp2.pyx* file (in the same folder as the above header), with wrappers for `Rectangle` and `Group2`:

```
# RECTANGLE
cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle()

# GROUP2
cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Group2:
        Group2(Rectangle rect0, Rectangle rect1) except +    

cdef class PyGroup2:
    cdef Group2 c_group2
    def __cinit__(self, Rectangle rect0, Rectangle rect1):
        self.c_group2 = Group2(rect0, rect1)
```

The extension is built via  a `setup.py` file that I call from command line (`python setup.py build_ext -i`):

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(Extension(
           name="grp2",                                # the extension name
           sources=["grp2.pyx"], # the Cython source 
           language="c++",                        # generate and compile C++ code
      )))
```

At this point I have the error in the `_cinint_` of `PyGroup2`:

> Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'Rectangle'

I suppose there is some mistake in my pyx file, but I cannot tell what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `PyRectangle` in the signatures of `def`-functions and `PyRectangle.c_rect` when passing rectangles to C++-functions.

That means your code should be:

```
cdef class PyGroup2:
    ...
    def __cinit__(self, PyRectangle rect0, PyRectangle rect1):
        self.c_group2 = Group2(rect0.c_rect, rect1.c_rect)
```

Read on for a more detailed explanation why.

---

All arguments passed to `def`-functions are Python-objects (i.e. of type `object` in Cython-parlance), after all those functions will be called from pure Python, which only knows Python-objects.

However, you can add some syntactic sugar and use "late-binding" in the signature of a `def`-function, for example, instead of

```
def do_something(n):
  ...
```

use

```
def do_something(int n):
  ...
```

Under the hood, Cython will transform this code to something like:

```
def do_something(n_):
   cdef int n = n_ # conversion to C-int
   ...
```

This automatic conversion is possible for builtin-types like `int` or `double`, because there is functionality in Python-C-API for these conversions (i.e. [`PyLong_AsLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLong), [`PyFloat_AsDouble`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/float.html#c.PyFloat_AsDouble)). Cython also handles the error checking, so you should not undertake these conversion manually.

However, for user-defined types/classes like your `Rectangle`-class such automatic conversion is not possible - Cython can only automatically convert to `cdef`-classes/extensions, i.e. `PyRectangle`, thus `PyRectangle` should be used in the signature:

```
cdef class PyGroup2:
    ...
    def __cinit__(self, PyRectangle rect0, PyRectangle rect1):
        ...
```

After Cython took care of conversion from `object` to `PyRectangle`, the last step from `PyRectangle` to `Rectangle` must be taken manually by utilizing the `c_rect` - pointer:

```
...
def __cinit__(self, PyRectangle rect0, PyRectangle rect1):
    self.c_group2 = Group2(rect0.c_rect, rect1.c_rect)
```

---

The rules are similar for `cpdef`-function, because they can be called from pure Python. The ["early binding"](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html) works only for types which Cython can automatically coverted from/to Python objects.

Unsurprisingly, the only function which can habe C++-classes in their signatures are the `cdef`-functions.

Comment: Very clear answer. This crucial point was not so easy to understand from the other sources I looked. Thank you